# Bundler error message "Revision master does not exist in the repository"

Tags: bundler, fido-u2f

When trying to install the gem "u2f" from the repo at "castle/ruby-u2f" I get an error message:

```
Fetching git://github.com/castle/ruby-u2f.git
fatal: Needed a single revision
Revision master does not exist in the repository git://github.com/castle/ruby-u2f.git. Maybe you misspelled it?
```

I cannot find any information about this error message. The text does not appear in any of the bundler source files, so I don't even know where to start debugging.

If anyone has any insight into the source and cause of this error, I'd love to know.

Comment: I can confirm getting a revision does not exist error for a revision that is definitely there in a public repo. Weird that I was able to use a different rev just fine.

Answer (score 28):

If you're trying to install a gem from a github source and got this, it may be because the repo changed its default branch from "master" to "main". Try adding `branch: 'main'` and see if it works.

The complete line in your gemfiles is then (comment by [@Ryan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4441760/ryan-kopf)):

```
gem 'gemname', git: 'github.com/gempath/gemname', branch: 'main'
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Not long ago the primary branch name for all repositories was changed from "master" to "main".

Comment: Still a matter as of today.

Answer (score 1):

Try pulling from the master branch